# Using Array Formulas With If Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to evaluate one of two slightly different `COUNTIFS` functions using an `IF` statement to determine which one to use, for each of about 5000 rows of a table.

**The formula follows:**

```
{=IF(ISBLANK(Current!$AL$2:$AL$5000),SUM(COUNTIFS(Current!$S$2:$S$5000,"*Open/Active*",Current!$AC$2:$AC$5000,Summary!K$3,Current!$V$2:$V$5000,$A$46:$A$47,Current!$AF$2:$AF$5000,"<="&DATE(2018,12,31))),SUM(COUNTIFS(Current!$S$2:$S$5000,"*Open/Active*",Current!$AC$2:$AC$5000,Summary!K$3,Current!$V$2:$V$5000,$A$46:$A$47,Current!$AL$2:$AL$5000,"<="&DATE(2018,12,31))))}
```

To give an idea of how I want this to work, the `AL` column has revised due dates, which not all rows in the table have.

If revised dates are not present, the `AL` column field should be blank, and the formula should count the number of rows matching the Original Due Date (`AF` column) criteria, along with other criteria shared between the two `COUNTIFS`.

If Revised Due Date column is not blank for a particular row, it should run the second `COUNTIFS` formula.

The output should provide a total count of "Open/Active" items, with `AC` column values matching that of the text cell `K3`, `V` column value matching those in `A46:47`, and a date in either Column `AL` or `AF` (based on the initial `IF` statement) that comes before `12/31/2018`.

For whatever reason, and I assume it has to do with my lack of knowledge/experience with arrays. The result always evaluates the formula as if that cell from the initial `IF` statement is blank, even when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The COUNTIFS expects a range in its criteria_range arguments; you cannot parse that range with an IF condition.

There is no need for an array formula nor to cut down full column references. The 'no-blanks' check can be performed in the COUNTIFS as well.

```
'first COUNTIFS with no-blanks added
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Current!$S:$S, "Open/Active", 
                     Current!$AC:$AC, Summary!K$3, 
                     Current!$V:$V, $A$46:$A$47, 
                     Current!$AL:$AL, "", 
                     Current!$AF:$AF, "<"&DATE(2019,1,1)))

'second COUNTIFS formula
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Current!$S:$S, "Open/Active",
                     Current!$AC:$AC, Summary!K$3, 
                     Current!$V:$V, $A$46:$A$47, 
                     Current!$AL:$AL, "<>", 
                     Current!$AL:$AL, "<"&DATE(2019,1,1)))
```

The SUMPRODUCT takes care of the multiple $A$46:$A$47 criteria.

Put 'If AL is blank use AF' together with 'If AL is not blank use AL' and you get,

```
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Current!$S:$S, "Open/Active", 
                         Current!$AC:$AC, Summary!K$3, 
                         Current!$V:$V, $A$46:$A$47, 
                         Current!$AL:$AL, "", 
                         Current!$AF:$AF, "<"&DATE(2019,1,1))),
     SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Current!$S:$S, "Open/Active",
                         Current!$AC:$AC, Summary!K$3, 
                         Current!$V:$V, $A$46:$A$47, 
                         Current!$AL:$AL, "<>", 
                         Current!$AL:$AL, "<"&DATE(2019,1,1))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. One trouble spot I am encountering is that
the following part of the formula is supposed to evaluate whether values in `Column V` match either of the text values in cells `A46` and `A47`:

`Current!$V:$V, $A$46:$A$47,`

Right now, the criteria part of this part of this line is being read into the formula with a `#VALUE` error. How would I define these cells as strings to be matched with?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce the problem. I just mocked up a second sample workbook (I had deleted the original I used to proof the formula) and it works as expected.

Comment: I just did some additional troubleshooting. I added back the wild card asterisks to `"Open/Active"` and changed the `$A$46:$A$47` to just `$A$47` and it worked as expected. 

I think the issue is with trying to match to either of two criteria cells. Should I break the formula out further to run a separate SUMPRODUCT for each of those cells, `A46` and `A47`?
That could get pretty cumbersome, as some of the other outputs will have more than two such cells to try to match on.

Comment: No, that would just be cumbersome,

Comment: Right, but is there anything else I could do? Putting in an `OR` statement to combine the two cells doesn't work, and my count is off (zero) when I use the logic from your original response.